# Translation of Related List

Tags: apex, related-list, translation, translation-workbench

Can I do translation of Related List Names? If not by Translation workbench, is there any other way?

Comment: Do you mean Change Rename Related List ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed with Translation workbench:

[image: Translation workbench]